# Как умножить и разделить на степень двойки в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Как умножить и разделить на степень двойки в ассемблере,используя смещение бит.32 битная платформа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Умножить на 2^k

```
shl eax, k
```

Разделить

```
shr eax, k  //беззнаковое
sar eax, k  //знаковое деление, в отличие от idiv округление к -Inf
```

Comment: ,а если требуется деление ,в результате которого получается дробное число:5/2 = 2.5?

Comment: В таком случае используете вещественное деление FDIV и т.п. команды сопроцессора или DIVPS из  sse2. Если нужно на битовом уровне работать - изменяете [экспоненту](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) - выделяете соответствующие 8 бит (для float32), добавляете или вычитаете k, записываете обратно (в принципе можно последовательностью rol+ add byteptr + ror)