# Разделить 64-битное число на два

Tags: ассемблер

Задано число от 0 до 10^18,требуется разделить на два.

Answer (score 0):

а что значит "разделить на 2"?

разделить на старшее и младшее 32 битное число?

```
mov rbx, rax
shr rbx, 32
and rax, 0FFFFFFFFh
```

результат в регистрах `eax`, `ebx`

или надо разделить на число 2?

```
shr rax, 1
```

Comment: [Видимо, второе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345430/)

Comment: если совсем корректно,чтобы учитывать факт переполнения,то нужно делать 'shr $1,%edx
  rcr $1,%eax'